# Autorefresh recent changes in ankhsvn

Tags: ankhsvn

I have question like in the title: how to setup ankhsvn to autorefresh status when someone commit something ? I want to see which file isn't latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need a newer version than the current stable release. Download it from http://ankhsvn.net/daily

Open View -> Pending Changes, go to the Recent Changes tab. Here you'll find a checkbox to enable/disable auto-refresh, and a dropdown to select the interval.

Comment: Thx I looking for something like this :D